# Custom Xamarin.Forms.Command with try catch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, command, try-catch, prism

I´ve copied the [Xamarin.Forms.Command](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Command.cs), and add in the Execute method an try catch that Publish an specific event (using EventAggregator de Prism) when my InvalidAppVersionException occurs.

The try catch doesn't work and I don't understand why.
Anyone can help me?

My custom Command code:

```
public class LudaAppCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
    readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public LudaAppCommand(Action<object> execute, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

        _execute = execute;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public LudaAppCommand(Action execute, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : this(o => execute(), eventAggregator)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
    }

    public LudaAppCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : this(execute, eventAggregator)
    {
        if (canExecute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));

        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public LudaAppCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : this(o => execute(), o => canExecute(), eventAggregator)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        if (canExecute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute != null)
            return _canExecute(parameter);

        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // TODO: Este try catch no funciona :(
        try
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
        catch (Exceptions.InvalidAppVersionException)
        {
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<Events.InvalidAppVersionEvent>().Publish();
        }
    }

    public void ChangeCanExecute()
    {
        EventHandler changed = CanExecuteChanged;
        changed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a try catch into the Action you pass into `public LudaAppCommand(Action<object> execute, ...)`

Comment: Yes, but this means add the same try catch in each function passed as action to the command constructor. I'm looking for a generic way to handle this exception through all my code.

Comment: How do we know it doesn't work? What about writing a unit test and share it here?